# HTML number input step validation doesn't work with value property

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, validation

I'm implementing a form where users should only be allowed to enter numbers with up to two decimal points (i.e. valid money amounts). I'm using Next.js (React) as my JS framework.

I found that, when entering a number with more than two decimals points, the following example opens a validation message informing me that the input is not valid. When clicking the submit button, the message opens again, and the form cannot be submitted ('submitted form' doesn't print on the console).

```html
<form
  onSubmit={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('submitted form');
  }}
>
  <input
    type="number"
    step={0.01}
    id="amount"
    name="amount"
  />
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

However once I control the input's value with value and onChange properties like so:

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState<string>('');
```

```html
<form
  onSubmit={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('submitted form');
  }}
>
  <input
    type="number"
    step={0.01}
    id="amount"
    name="amount"
    value={value}
    onChange={(e) => setValue(e.currentTarget.value)}
  />
  <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

validation for the step property doesn't affect the form'd validity anymore. If I set any other validation properties like min/max/required, the form can still not be submitted unless the requirements are met, but when I input a value that has too many decimal points, the form can be submitted through the submit button.

I also tried printing the input's validity on every change, and the input is marked as invalid once the number of decimal points exceeds 2 (checked with `input.checkValidity()`), the form is marked as valid though and can be submitted.

I couldn't find anything about this anywhere, in particular because this seems to be exclusive to the step property. Also, I can hardly imagine this is the intended behavior of html forms...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: I just noticed some more weird behavior: when I submit the form with a value like 10.12345, then remove the extra digits (so I'm left with 10.12) and then try to submit the form by pressing enter inside the input, it tells me that the values is invalid and the next valid numbers would be 10.11345 and 10.12345

Answer (score 0):

i think you forgot one think, that's the value button, you can try add value in button "submit" like this

```html
<form
  onSubmit={(e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('submitted form');
  }}
>
  <input
    type="number"
    step={0.01}
    id="amount"
    name="amount"
    value={value}
    onChange={(e) => setValue(e.currentTarget.value)}
  />
  <button type="submit" value="Submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: That doesn't change anything about the behavior unfortunately... I just copied your snippet, and it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

What fixed my problem was using a `min` value on the input